# setText() not working inside the adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm doing an Adroid app to practice a litle bit but I'm finding some trouble here. I have this adapter to list some products. I can see them in the activity but with the TextView empty.

Do you know why setText() function is not working?
I think it will be a stupid syntax mistake or something like that but I can't find it out.

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Cursor cursor;
private boolean full;

public CardAdapter(Cursor c) {
    cursor = c;
    full = cursor.moveToFirst();
}

@Override
public CardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.product_row, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        if (full) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                holder.productName.setText(name);
                full = cursor.moveToNext();
                if(!full) cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "Error while trying to get rows from database");
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int i = cursor.getCount();
    if(i > 0) {
        full = true;
        return i;
    }
    else {
        full = false;
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView productName;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        productName = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productName));
    }
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Changing *onBindViewHolder*:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));

                holder.productName.setText(name);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "Error while trying to get rows from database");
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

TextView xml:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/productName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
```

In mainACtivity, there's this on the onCreate():

```
    pRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    pRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    pLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    productManager = new ProductManager(this);
    Cursor c = productManager.getProducts();

    pAdapter = new CardAdapter(c);
    pRecyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
    pRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(pLayoutManager);
```

**Solution**
Because it's in a comment I posted here too: the textColor was set to white. Genius.

Thank you!

Comment: try to debug and check for the full is true or not and the name is coming proper.

Comment: and one more major problem is you are not looping it properly try do while to achieve all cursor object.  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
          String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));

       }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();

Comment: @AnkitAman but the adapter iterates by itself through _onBindViewHolder_ using _getItemCount()_, isn't it? Maybe I'm confusing things.

Comment: @AnkitAman also when debuging it enters just one time inside _onBindViewHolder_ and gets properly the name

Comment: Adapter iterates base on counts  (cursor.getCount();). You can use its position to get the item from the index. But in your case, you have to iterate your own. otherwise every time your full block gets called which end up no result.

Comment: Got the same "white problem" - for some reason the text was white, although it is not declared to use that color anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapter iterates base on counts i.e `cursor.getCount()`. You can use its position to get the item from the index. But in your case you have to iterate your own. Otherwise every time your full block gets called which will end up in no result.

try:-

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
       String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
   }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

At the end call `notifyItemPositionChanged()` and pass the same position for the view to get refreshed.

Comment: like this inside the _do_ or at the end of _onBindViewHolder_ function? 
'this.notifyItemChanged(position);'

Comment: at the end call  after closing notifyItemChanged(position);

Comment: try to debug and check whether do while is working with proper output or not.

Comment: it's getting the name properly and iterating just 1 time as there's only one row in the database, so apparently it's doing well but still not showing the text

Comment: check for visibility of textView inside xml and also try notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition) putting it inside do while

Comment: check your recycler view has height match_parent or not

Comment: Yes, it has. I don't know what's happening

Comment: hmm.. that weird. have you added layout manager to your recyclerview

Comment: set layoutManager before setting adapter

Comment: Done but still nothing

Comment: you have set your text color as "#FFFFFF which is == white just change the color might be it is matching with your background color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if full is true and name is not null.If name is null or empty then it will set nothing else set whatever it has in name variable on Textview.So please debug or add Log to print value in name.

Comment: it is getting the name